# SpeechRecognizer gives results in many languages, but I only want one language

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I know this question has been asked a number of times, but I have not found an answer that works for me. 
Let's say I want to recognize Swedish. I say "på" and I do get that word in the result list, but I also get the English word "paw" which is pronounced the same. Is there there any way to restrict the result list to words in only one language?

I have tried EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE when calling RecognizerIntent.ACTION_GET_LANGUAGE_DETAILS, but it doesn't restrict my result list when doing the actual speech recognition. The EXTRA_LANGUAGE does not make any difference.

Limiting the result list length doesn't work either, because the matches for my preferred language doesn't necessarily come first in the result list. This is not a problem with Swedish, the same things happen when I use Spanish as selected and preferred language.

The app that I am writing needs to recognize single words more often than complete sentences.

```
Locale def = Locale.getDefault();
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getApplication().getPackageName());
//intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, def.toLanguageTag());
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, def.toLanguageTag()); 

intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.EXTRA_ADDITIONAL_LANGUAGES", new String[]{def.toLanguageTag()});
speechInput = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(MainActivity.this);
speechInput.setRecognitionListener(recognitionListener);
speechInput.startListening(intent);
```